# Why this question is [closed as off-topic]?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was searching for "**How to prompt a user to choose a directory in android?**" and run into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog).
I think the question is well written, and got some useful answers. Matter of fact, the question has 77 upvotes and 44 favorites.
But the question was closed a [Moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber?tab=tags) who is not active in the android tag.
(Another good reason to welcome the gold tag feature)
Anyway, IMHO I don't think it as off-topic, rather it is a very helpful question.
I have voted to re-open it.
In contrast, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587325/how-to-select-folder-in-android) has all the ingredients to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Slow down.  Look at the kinds of answers that the question is attracting (or at least in part).  A lot of them are links to some off-site resource, which isn't allowed here.  However, the top couple of answers are useful and aren't link-only.  A question like this is a good candidate to be edited to better convey that it's not specifically looking for a third-party resource.

Comment: @Makoto, you are right. But the question in itself is not asking for a third-party resource. Maybe starting the question with [Does anyone know .... ?] is like to attract off-site links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it should be reopened. The reason for the closing was probably because of the last paragraph which sounds like a resource request.

> "I would be extremely grateful if someone could point out a Dialog that would allow the user to browse folders and select a file, and return the path."

The (highest) answers however all provide a solution using the standard libraries which indicates it can be done without external libraries. With a cleanup of the question itself this should be fine so I voted to reopen (I'm not editing it myself yet to avoid interference with the community discussion).

Comment: It's not *just* the last paragraph. The entire thing reads as they're looking for a library or code snippet. Just because a couple of the answers actually provide the code doesn't make it any less of a resource request... If anything, a better reason would have just been "too broad."

Comment: Are you saying that SO is *not* the right place to ask for help with finding a library or code snippet? If not SO, where? I looked at the original post linked to in the question, and it looks like it has quite a lot of fruitful information.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic point 4

Comment: Even if the question itself can (should) be classified as off-topic, my understanding is that the quality of the answers should also be considered before closing a question. In this case, the answers turned the question into somewhat of a gem, which is also demonstrated by the upvotes and favorites. I would say the best approach here is to edit the original question to reflect the general question and make it easier to find through search engines. The result would definetly be valuable.

Answer (score -1):

I feel compelled to chip in and say that the "Closed as off-topic" designation often seems arbitrary to me, and rarely actually seems helpful.  I think stackoverflow policy makers should use this feature with considerably more reserve than I see "out there". Just my opinion.