# Please explain why this question was closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I got [a question about android SQLite alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246376/data-storage-without-sqlite) closed as off topic. As [@Makoto says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257963/why-this-question-is-closed-as-off-topic#comment33486_257963) to a [similar meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257963/why-this-question-is-closed-as-off-topic)

> A question like this is a good candidate to be edited to better
>   convey that it's not specifically looking for a third-party resource.

There have been edits (the last two days ago), which rewrote the question to make it more clear that I was not looking for

> a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource,

and I flagged to re-open.

**Does it take some time for it to get reopened, or is it still off-topic for SO?** What could be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is great clarification in [@Ixrec's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7585/182749) at meta.programmers.

Additionally to it being off-topic, the

> requirements simply aren't specific enough to make the question *answerable*.

It might belong, but

> the requirements you specify (which would be relevant to an answer) are:
>
> > They do not need transactions, ACID, and such. They need to be queried, though.
>
> Which is not enough to rule out any form of data storage at all. Even
> using a simple text file which you read into a `std::map<X, Y>` at
> startup is enough to allow basic querying. Also, I'm not sure I
> believe that any use case doesn't require any part of ACID; maybe you
> don't need things like rollback but I'm sure everyone wants atomicity
> and consistency at least.

Answer (score 6):

The question has traits qualifying it in some sense for multiple close reasons:

- It's a rather broad question;
- The "*what would be an approach*" part (still kind of) reads somewhat as if you're looking for a tool / solution / framework (i.e. an "offsite resource");
- The "*Which are advantages and disadvantages*" part is clearly asking for opinions;

It's also somewhat unclear, maybe not so much the question itself, but to some degree it would be unclear how to decide which answer is the "definitive" answer.

My gut feeling says it would probably be very hard to make the question a good fit for Stack Overflow and still get your underlying question answered.

As to the other part of your question:

> Does it take some time for it to get reopened

Yes. Multiple re-open votes would be needed before it's actually reopened. There's [a review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/) for that, and it might take a bit before enough people have voted to reach a decision.

Comment: _"Which are advantages and disadvantages..."_ make this question a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Please don't recommend other sites unless you know their scope....

Comment: Thanks for commenting @gnat and enderland. Point taken, honest mistake. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: After an edit (addressing the part quoted by @gnat), the question was deemed a candidate for Programmers.SE if it got a huge update on requirements. Thus, the part about Programmers *was* helpful.